# PHP error_log() not writing to disk in cron job

Tags: php, cron, error-log

When running PHP scripts as cron jobs, the error handler works but the error_log() function doesn't write to disk.  I included these lines in the script run through cron in case it was because the php.ini values weren't getting picked up, but still no output to the error log.

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('error_log', LOG_FOLDER . 'error_log.txt');
```

Error handling in general is working as expected, and the error messages appear in the cron output email that I get.

As a workaround I could detect that the script is running as a cron job by checking $_SERVER, and then writing to the error log using fopen(), etc.  But I was hoping I could get it set up right and just use error_log().

Comment: Are you sure `LOG_FOLDER` is correctly defined? What does `echo LOG_FOLDER . 'error_log.txt'` produce?

Comment: You could just redirect the output of the cron. In crontab:
php yourcommand.php &> /path/to/error_log.txt

Comment: I have printed out the LOG_FOLDER and it's echoing the correct path, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just realized that is was just my mistake and the LOG_FOLDER was actually not correct, there was a folder missing.  :)